# Attempting to position font awesome icon in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a basic div with an icon and some text. If I don't try and change the size of the icon it lines up perfect.

But I want the icon to be bigger but still sit centred in the text. The problem is the icon doesn't sit centred in the div, it seems to move up so the text ends up lined to the bottom of the icon and the icon sits higher in the div. I expect the text to be centred in the icon as the icon would be centred in the div....

You can see it on this fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/8mjN7/1/

Pulling in

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS

```
div {

    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    Foo bar
</div>
```

Comment: - give the div a height - and add a line height with the height of the div  to the globe ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `vertical-align` property as follows:

```
i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

see demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9ATq8/

**Note:** It is necessary to specify `height: 30px` for the `i` element and `line-height: 40px` of the parent container, otherwise, any default values may not work as expected.

CSS table-cell also works but the added complexity is not needed in this case.

Comment: bingo! I thought there would be a way without using table-cell! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to make sure the icon is in the middle. The padding & line-height i think are the two most important.

```
background: rgba(143, 211, 157, 1);
border-radius: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: inline-block; 
font-size: 55px; 
height: 45px;
width: 45px;
padding: 40px 45px 40px 35px;
line-height: 45px !important;
transition: .5s;
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to display the div like a table like this?

```
div {
    display:table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

i {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8mjN7/2/)**

CSS:

```
div {

    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display:table;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}

i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```